# Using XML response as variable in Postman

Tags: postman

> Blockquote
> Hi All,

I have a question. I just started using Postman, so please sorry if I'm not using all the correct technical terms.

I want to have a Envirionment variable in postman that contains several XML tags.

F.e.

```
<Storess>
      <Store>
         <Id>322</Id>
      </Store>
      <Store>
         <Id>323</Id>
      </Store>
      <Store>
         <Id>324</Id>
      </Store>
</Storess>
```

I want everything between the tags `<Storess>` and `</Storess>` to be copied to the environment variable so that I can use {{Storess}} in the next request that i'm sending.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful: https://www.marklogic.com/blog/postman-test-scripting/

In the test script of the first request, you can set the result in an environment variable like this:

```
var result = pm.response.text();

console.log(result);

result = result.replace("<Storess>", "").replace("</Storess>", "").trim();

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Storess", result);

console.log(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("Storess"));
```

You will be able to get the information in the next request like this:

```
{{Storess}}
```

If you want the XML inside the variable Storess to be well-formatted, you'll need to work it out a little bit.